# Unable to get the SumProduct property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function, sumproduct

This is the dataset structure. I want to put the result of the operation "Sumproduct" in the yellow rows.

[image]

I have some problems with my code. When I run it, I get the message "Unable to get the SumProduct property of the WorksheetFunction class". I have read that it happens when you use the Range as a string but in my case, I'm creating the variables first. Could you help me to figure it out the problem?

```
Dim im1 As Long, startpoint As Long, lastPoint As Long
Dim a As Range, b As Range, c As Range, d As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction

startpoint = 6
lastPoint = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
Set ws = Sheets("tabfinal")
Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction

Do While (startpoint < lastPoint)

For i = startpoint To lastPoint
      If (Cells(i, 1).Value = "") Then
        Exit For
      End If
    Next

im1 = i - 1
    Set a = ws.Range("F" & startpoint & ":F" & im1)
    Set b = ws.Range("G" & startpoint & ":G" & im1)

Cells(i, 7).Value = wsf.SumProduct(a, b)
startpoint = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do. You are 'applying' `SumProduct` on column `F` and `G` and showing the results in one of those columns i.e.in column `G`? There is a limit how large the numbers can be.

Comment: I add the dataset image to give more context to the question.